# PHP, multidimensional arrays: to intersected events with days of the month

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I want to build a movie timetable. I have $array1 containing the movie titles and airing dates and times:

```
array = 
    0: array = 
      Title: string = American Beauty
      Date: string = 25/09/2012
      Time: string = 15:00 - 16:20
    1: array = 
      Title: string = The Godfather 
      Date: string = 25/09/2012
      Time: string = 16:20 - 18:20
    2: array =
 Title: string = Pulp Fiction
Date: string = 26/09/2012
Time: string = 15:00 - 16:20
```

And I have $array2 containing the days of the month grouped by Mondays, Tuesday s, Wednesday s, Thursday s and Fridays (no movies during the weekend)

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 17
            [3] => 24
            [4] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 26
            [4] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 27
            [4] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 14
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 28
            [4] => 
        )

)
```

I need to intersect these two arrays so I can print under day 25 the movie “American Beauty” also under day 25 “The Godfather” and under day 26 “Pulp Fiction”.

Meaning I need to print:

```
SEPTEMBER 2012

    Monday Tuesday                          Wednesday ....
    3        4                                  5

    10       11                                 12

    17       18                                 19

    24       25                                 26                    
           15:00-16:20 American Beauty       15:00-16:20 Pulp Fiction
           16:20-18:20 The Godfather
```

My tries so far:

```
foreach( $array1  as $key => $value ) 
{
    $theTime  = $value['Time'];
    $theTime  = explode("/", $theTime );
    $days[] = $theTime  [0];
    $months[] = $theTime  [1];
}
```

So I have all the airing days in array $days but from here I don’t know how to follow or even if this approach is the correct one.

Here's how I get $array2:

```
$month = 9; 
$year = 2012;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) 
{
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month , $i, $year);

    if (date("n", $timestamp) == $month ) 
    {
        $day = date("N", $timestamp);

        // Monday  1 to Friday 5 
        if ($day == 1 OR $day <= 5) {
            $array2[$day][] = date("j", $timestamp); 
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, I’m stuck.

Thanks very much

Comment: what do you want at the end? Do you want array2 to contain the movies?

Comment: I'm editing the post so the goal is clearer

Comment: First you want to iterate on array2 first, since you want to show all the days even if there are no movies. Then, you can iterate array1 to match the day with the Date.

Comment: how can I match the day with the Date?

Comment: You don't need the second array. PHP can easily calculates those dates for you.

Comment: The second array is needed because I'm grouping days in Mondays, Tuesdays and so on .. please see how in my post, I've edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you will iterate over $array1 and parse the date of the movie.
Then, you will look inside array2 if your day is there

```
foreach($array1 as $movie){

    $movieDate = new DateTime($movie);
    //as you indexed $array2 with monday = 1 -> friday = 5 you can use the "w" format
    if(isset($array2[$movieDate->format("w"))){

        $array[$movieDate->format("j")][] = $movie;
    }
}
```

I made some mutation in your output array, it becomes :
    SEPTEMBER 2012

```
Monday Tuesday                          Wednesday ....
3=>[]        4 =>[]                                 5=>[]

10=>[]       11    =>[]                             12=>[]

17=>[]       18   =>[]                              19=>[]

24 =>[]      25=>[                                 26   =>[                 
       15:00-16:20 American Beauty,       15:00-16:20 Pulp Fiction]
       16:20-18:20 The Godfather]
```

Comment: that's why I said I brough mutations. It's impossible to do as you want